# What are your best practices to compile only a part of the document or presentation (or how do you prepare the big ones)?

Tags: compiling, best-practices, include

I see that there a number of questions ([A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40760/best-practice-on-organising-your-preamble), [B](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99730/what-are-best-practices-for-package-authors-to-deal-with-package-conflicts), [C](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136329/best-practice-for-fixing-a-clash-between-packages-without-altering-the-sty-file), [D](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141300/best-practice-of-latex-fold-editing-in-vim), [E](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112566/whats-the-best-solution-to-split-a-tex-file-into-separate-compiled-files)) on best practices, none of them answer the issue I am going to talk about.

(**UPDATE:** This issue has also been discussed in [this *newer* question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375775/14103))

We all need to prepare large documents (or slides) from time-to-time. And once you have reached a certain number of pages, you find that compiling the whole document takes a substantial time, which you need to do to check that the part you have written is error free, specially if it contains a number of images.

To circumvent the situation, I have used the following practices over years to keep compile time at minimum.

- **Divide the document in to many chapters**: The chapters are put in separate files. Only the one I am working one is uncommented.

  ```
   \documentclass{book}

   \begin{document}

   %\input {chapterone.tex}
   \input {chaptertwo.tex}
   %\input {chapterthree.tex}
   %\input {chapterfour.tex}

   \end{document}
  ```

The above technique can also be used for `\include`.

- **Keep a preamble replica of the main file in a temporary file *(build file)***: I use this technique when I am preparing a presentation with many slides, say a hundred. Prepare a main file, copy it to another build file. Delete everything between
  `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in the build file. Prepare a slide (or a group of slides) in the build file. Cut and paste the contents between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in the build file to relevant location in the main file only when satisfied with the output (image locations, overfull boxes etc.)

---

We can hear your inputs about the best practices you *practice* when a you are preparing a document or presentation from scratch.

---

Now, I have failed to find a good answer in the case when you have finished the whole document or presentation and now you need tweaking the small things, may be edit a text here, add an image there. What will be your best practice?

Perhaps, again keeping only one chapter uncommented will be usable here. But what about large presentations? May be adding a `\end{document}` just after the point-of-change will be beneficial, but only if you can put that before midpoint of the file.

Commenting a part of the file will also work, but that is error-prone, at least for me.

Comment: For chess puzzles I use a work file (with templates for cut and paste), then copy each slide to a file until it fills to 100 puzzles, then I start another file.

Comment: @JohnKormylo So, your work file is something like my build file? I am not very familiar with preparing chess puzzles using LaTeX.

Comment: Yes, except for the templates which stay in the work file.

Comment: To mark lines inside lists as code, indent them by 8 spaces instead of 4 ;-) (sorry for the late comment, my connection is not very good today...)

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks. I was having to hard time trying to find out how to make them look like code. Though I had repeatedly selected the code and pressed the code button. Then I gave up, thinking that somebody else will teach me how to do that.

Comment: related: [Minimization of the time it takes to preview a large beamertex file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108254)

Comment: @cmhughes A very good one with only one downside. You need to painstakingly label the slides you want to work on.

Comment: The [standalone](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone/) package can help...

Comment: true, but if it's a choice between labelling a slide and waiting a long time to compile, I know which I choose :)

Comment: Please read some LaTeX documentation about `\includeonly`.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11311/how-to-include-a-document-into-another-document, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11221/bind-reports-articles-into-a-book-but-keep-the-ability-to-compile-them-individu, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8198/combine-several-chapters-separate-files-in-to-one-report

Comment: Related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375775/how-to-compile-update-parts-of-my-document-only-while-still-producing-a-complet?rq=1

Comment: @RobertPollak The current question is almost ten years old. The one you mentioned is six years plus old. Anyway, I am going to put a link inside the current question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There has not been any answer per se to the question so far. But we got some
very helpful comments (and links). The following is an accumulated 
version of responses received so far (with further link traversals
where necessary).

---

The following are not mutually exclusive and definitely not
categorizations. Once you get the hang of them (all or some), you are free
exercise your own styles and tricks to get your work done,
a little faster.

---

**Divide the document into individual files:** Rather than preparing single
large file, the document should be divided into separate .tex files

There are number of ways to choose from.

- If you are using `\input` to include your files, you can simply comment out
  the relevant command for the file which you do not want to `\input`.
- If you are using `\include`, the scenario is almost similar to the
  above. But the added benefit will be that this allow you to include
  specific files using `\includeonly{filename,filename2,...}` to save
  times.

An excellent discussion on LaTeX modular documents can be found
[here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents). Relative
benefits of `\input` versus `\include` have been further elaborated
 [in this
question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include).

**Effectively Build only a Part of the Presentation File:** This is more
applicable when you are making minor changes to your presentations.
Your friend here is the `\includeonlyframes` command, which allows you
to selectively include some frames. The following
is an excerpt from the [The beamer Class
User Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf),

> `\includeonlyframes{⟨frame label list⟩}`
>
> This command behaves a little bit like the `\includeonly` command:
>   Only the frames mentioned in the list are included. All other frames
>   are suppressed. Nevertheless, the section and subsection commands are
>   still executed, so that you still have the correct navigation bars. By
>   labeling the current frame as, say, current and then saying
>   `\includeonlyframes{current}`, you can work on a single frame quickly.
>   The ⟨frame label list⟩ is a comma-separated list (without spaces) of
>   the names of frames that have been labeled. To label a frame, you must
>   pass the option `label=⟨name⟩` to the `\frame` command or frame
>   environment.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> \includeonlyframes{example1,example3}
> \frame[label=example1]
> {This frame will be included. }
> \frame[label=example2]
> {This frame will not be included. }
> \frame{This frame will not be included.}
> \againframe{example1} % Will be included
> ```

See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108255/14103) to get
some very helpful examples. Also do not miss this [interesting
idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107454/can-includeonlyframes-be-modified-to-take-a-wild-card)
of modifying `\includeonlyframes` to take a wild card. Do you see the prospect here? You can label your similar (group of) slides with names
which can be represented as `<string>*`. Someone even
suggested that this feature should be added to the next beamer
release.

**Use a Temporary/Work File:** This method is mostly applicable when you
are working (most likely building for the first time) on a presentation or
something like a chess puzzle.

For presentations, prepare a main file, copy it to another build
file. Delete everything between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in
the build file. Prepare a slide (or a group of slides) in the build
file. Cut and paste the contents between `\begin{document}` and
`\end{document}` in the build file to relevant location in the main file
only when satisfied with the output (image locations, overfull boxes
etc.)

For chess puzzles, use a work file (with templates for cut and paste),
then copy each slide to a file until it fills to a number of puzzles,
then start another file.

**`standalone` package:** This package allows TeX pictures or other TeX
code in sub-files to be compiled standalone or as part of a main
document. It also provides support for pictures with beamer overlays.

A detailed description of this package will make the answer very
lengthy. You will get more help reading the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf). I found
[this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11318/14103) facilitating
a quick learning. Also, see this [interesting discussion on floats in
`standalone`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15416/14103).

Comment: In addition to using the standalone package for floats/pictures. I also use it in my chapters, allowing me to compile a chapter by itself and/or include it in the full report/book.