# Tips on large tex files

Tags: folders

I want to write a solution manual for a maths book which is about 900 pages.

I want it to include detailed solutions to all exercises as as well summaries for every chapter.

The file will obviously be quite large. I'd love to hear any tips on handling such large files, such as breaking it into several files etc...

Comment: Please see this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142417/14103).

Comment: If you are not including graphics files, even a 900 page .tex file is not "large" by today's standards. Compare with a Word or other binary file format and you'll find that the .tex file, being just text, isn't that large at all. My guess is that it could easily fit on a floppy. Oh wait, there aren't any floppies anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are basically two possibilities, both deal with splitting into several files

1. Include each file with the `\input{filename}` command
2. Include each file with the `\include{filename}` command

The second way always adds a pagebreak.

Regardless which style you apply, I would split the large file in logically parts, such as chapters or sections, but not into subsections.

Please note, that you cannot nest `\include` commands, in that case, you have to use `\input` in deeper hierarchies.

If you want to test some parts only, you could use `\includeonly` command, say

```
\documentclass{article}
%Starting stuff
\includeonly{section1,section6}%
\begin{document}
%Something to be done before formatting etc. of solutions
\include{section1}
\include{section2}
\include{section3}
\include{section4}
\include{section5}
\include{section6}
% Other stuff here
\end{document}
```

This will include only the files with section1 and section6, although the other ones are given explicitly in the `\include` statement.

Please also have a look on the `filecontents` package.

Comment: If you don't want pagebreak after include use the `newclude` package. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209065/to-have-no-pagebreak-after-include-in-latex

Comment: @NicholasHamilton: Good to know, I wasn't aware of that package. Thanks for that clue!

Comment: Just be aware that if you use `newclude` (or equivalent) and also `includeonly{...}` as a means to increase compilation speed when you are working on your document, without an explicit break (`\clearpage`) before each `include{...}` the layout may actually be very different in your final document, compared to what you are working on depending on how the sections NOT listed in (and before) the `includeonly{...}` command finish.

Comment: In other words, the there is a very good reason why `include{...}` by default starts on a new page, and that is to ensure layout consistency on the assumption you may be using the `includeonly{...}` command at some stage.